# How do I prevent changing buffer when using the :bufdo command?

Tags: vim

This command replaces some text in all my buffers:

```
:bufdo %s/some_text/other_text/ge | update
```

When running this command, the buffer of the current window is changed to the last buffer affected by `:bufdo`, as explained in `:help :bufdo`:

```
The last buffer (or where an error occurred) becomes
the current buffer.
```

I know it's possible to prevent the buffer from being changed, but I don't remember how.

Comment: This might be helpful. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers.

Comment: @RSahu: Those commands in the bottom will certainly accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I'm pretty certain there was a simple flag that did the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

You can save off the current buffer before running the command, then jump to it after:

```
:let buf=bufnr('%') | exec 'bufdo some_command' | exec 'b' buf
```

Comment: Should be bufnr('%') to get current buffer number.

Comment: You're correct, thanks. I assumed it worked like winnr() and tabpagenr(). Apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
" Like bufdo but restore the current buffer.
function! BufDo(command)
  let currBuff=bufnr("%")
  execute 'bufdo ' . a:command
  execute 'buffer ' . currBuff
endfunction
com! -nargs=+ -complete=command Bufdo call BufDo(<q-args>)
```

Reference: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers#

Answer (score 2):

My [ArgsAndMore plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4152) has a `:Bufdo` alternative to `:bufdo` that returns to the original buffer (and similar variants for `:argdo` etc.)